# Postgres JSONB: query by negative numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, latitude-longitude, jsonb

I am trying to query based on lat and lng values but the rows returned aren't matching my query when the value store is negative. However when i query positive values it works as expected. I am wondering if there is a specific way i need to format my queries.

Here are some example queries to prove the weird results:

```
QUERY 1
=======
db_development=# select address from listing where 'address.coords.latitude' < '40';

no rows returned.

QUERY 2
=======
db_development=# select address from listing where 'address.coords.latitude' > '40';

returned address: 
{  
  "city":"Heathmere",
  "state":"VIC",
  "coords":{  
    "latitude":-38.19523969999999,
    "longitude":141.6158994
  },
  "number":"1235",
  "street":"Princes Highway",
  "country":"Australia",
  "zipcode":"3305",
  "formatted":"Riversleigh, 1235 Princes Hwy, Heathmere VIC 3305, Australia"
}
```

As you can see i am trying to find the rows where the latitude is less than 40, but that returns no row. However when i check greater than 40 it returns the row where the latitude to -38.19523969999999.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems or perhaps two versions of the same problem is more accurate. In your query:

```
select address from listing where 'address.coords.latitude' > '40'
```

`'address.coords.latitude'` is a string literal, not a path into the `address` JSON; `'40'` is also a string literal, not the number `40`. So your WHERE clause is simply comparing two string literals, it isn't comparing the `latitude` embedded in the `address` column with the number `40`. That means that the WHERE clause in your first query is always false:

```
=> select 'address.coords.latitude' < '40' as correct;
 correct 
---------
 f
(1 row)
```

and the WHERE clause in your second query is always true:

```
=> select 'address.coords.latitude' > '40' as confused;
 confused 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

If you want to dig into your `address` JSON, you want to use the [`#>>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE):

> `#>>` `text[]`
>   Get JSON object at specified path as text

so you'd say:

```
address #>> array['coords', 'latitude']
```

to look at the embedded `latitude`; you could also use the [`jsonb_extract_path_text` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) if you or your tools don't like the `#>>` operator. Then you'd need to cast that `text` value to a number to get the comparison to work properly and compare that number to a plain (numeric) `40`:

```
select address
from listing
where (address #>> array['coords', 'latitude'])::numeric > 40
```

Similarly for your first query:

```
select address
from listing
where (address #>> array['coords', 'latitude'])::numeric < 40
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working as you expect is you are comparing JSON text to a text value.

You should cast the JSON value to the appropriate type, which is numeric, and compare to a number.

For example:

```
    select address from listing where ('address.coords.latitude')::numeric < 40;
```

Comment: But `'address.coords.latitude'` is still just a string, not a path into the JSON.